# Counting Rows for Grouping and Paging

Tags: jquery

I have the following code where I am trying to pagenext and previous for table rows

```
$( "a.paginate" ).click( function( e ) {
e.preventDefault();
if ( $( this ).attr( "id" ) == "next" ) {
//what to write here? 
// firstrecord should be between 0 and max rows
// somehow page size has to be added to the firstrecord
} else {
//what to write here?
// pagesize has to be subtracted, but unable to figure how to
}
paginate( firstRecord, pageSize );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99xAU/1/

Can anybody help me sort how to make the code work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified
>   by a range of indices.

to define the elements to display in the current page.

Code:

```
var firstRecord = 0;
var pageSize = 4;
var tableRows = $("#movie tbody tr");

$("a.paginate").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tmpRec = firstRecord;
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "next") {
        tmpRec += pageSize;
    } else {
        tmpRec -= pageSize;
    }
    if (tmpRec < 0 || tmpRec > tableRows.length) return
    firstRecord = tmpRec;
    paginate(firstRecord, pageSize);
});

var paginate = function (start, size) {
    var end = start + size;
    tableRows.hide();
    tableRows.slice(start, end).show();
}


paginate(firstRecord, pageSize);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H9JBT/

### UPDATE

For hide/show next/prev button you can check if the first/last element in visible using [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Code:

```
var paginate = function (start, size) {
    var end = start + size;
    tableRows.hide();
    tableRows.slice(start, end).show();
        $(".paginate").show();
    if (tableRows.eq(0).is(":visible")) $('#previous').hide();
        if (tableRows.eq(tableRows.length-1).is(":visible")) $('#next').hide();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LPwVB/

Comment: Thanks so much Irvin. For a large table, will Slice() give a better performance or eq() as Ionica suggests. Thanks

Comment: if the table rows are 4 or < 4, the next/previous button still show up. How to avoid that?

Comment: Sure. will it be possible to add some comments directly in your fiddle, explaining your code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you can count the number of rows currently described with:

```
var tablerows = $("#movie tr).length;
```

This will work once. The problem then comes that you won't know what the first record should be.  I'd suggest adding an ID to every table row.  For the "next" pagination I'd go like this:

```
var firstRecord = $("#movie tr:last").prop("id");
```

for last pagination I'd go like this:

```
var firstRecord = $("#movie tr").eq(1) - pageSize //whatever page size is it should always be smaller than the Id.
```

of course, this assumes that the IDs will always be consecutive, which depends largely on how you're getting your data to populate the table.  If we're assuming that YOU'RE the one populating the table from a JSON source that you're caching client side that doesn't have IDs already assigned, for example, you can assign the ID as you populate the table.  Otherwise I'd suggest handling the pagination server side using skip and limit functions on the database

Comment: unfortunately adding an id is not an option I have

Comment: @user2897587 okay, what's the datasource?

Comment: No datasource. If you check my jsfiddle, my table contains 9 rows, tomorrow may have 20 rows and so on. I want to page them in a  group of 4.

Comment: @user2897587 so...you want to paginate a statically populated table? For fun?  I don't understand the point of this.

Comment: The problem with trying to paginate with no datastore is where are the other pages comingfrom? where does the current page go? If you're dead set on using only javascript you could make a json object with all the data to draw from or you could play with ajax to only keep the table data you need.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use `eq(...)` function or `:eq(...)` selector.

Your function becomes:

```
/*
 *    Paginate function
 *
 * */
var paginate = function( start, size ) {

    // first page    
    if (start - size < 0) {

        // hide "Previous" link
        $("#previous").hide();

    // not the first page
    } else {

        // show it
        $("#previous").show();
    }

    // last page
    if (start + size >= $tableRows.length) {
        // hide the "Next" link
        $("#next").hide();
    // not the last page
    } else {
        // show it
        $("#next").show();
    }

    // hide all table rows
    $tableRows.hide();

    // each row from `start` to `start + size`
    for (var i = start; i < start + size; ++i) {

        // if index is greater than table row length
        if (i > $tableRows.length) {

            // we are on the last page
            $("#next").hide();

            // return
            return;
        }

        // show the current row
        $tableRows.eq(i).show();
    }
};
```

And in the click handler just increment or decrement the `firstRecord` variable.

```
if ($( this ).attr( "id" ) == "next" ) {
    firstRecord += pageSize;
} else {
    firstRecord -= pageSize
}
```

Then call `paginate(firstRecord, pageSize)` function:

```
paginate( firstRecord, pageSize );
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/99xAU/6/)

Comment: Thanks again, can you explain your code in the jsfiddle itself

Comment: I found a bug..if the table rows are 4 or < 4, the next button still shows. Another bug - http://jsfiddle.net/99xAU/4/ if you scroll to the last page and hit previous, the Next link disappears.

Comment: @user2897587 Some checks were missing. See the edit and the inline comments.